# Overriding Active Query construct in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, controller

I have the following trying to pull out a selection of Model instances from my DB with this:

```
@coasters = Coaster.joins(:park).order('parks.name ASC').order('coasters.name ASC')
```

Near the end of my `index` action I need to override the order part of the above query so I do the following:

```
@coasters = @coasters.except(:joins).reorder('order ASC')
```

But I get this error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "parks" LINE 1: SELECT  "coasters".* FROM "coasters"  ORDER BY
>   parks.name AS...
>                                                          ^ : SELECT  "coasters".* FROM "coasters"  ORDER BY parks.name ASC, coasters.name
>   ASC, "order" ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0

Any ideas as to how I can solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the lazy load feature and do not perform any order at all, before you are sure on what sorting you need.

```
@coasters = Coaster.where(...).joins(...)
```

and then

```
@coasters = @coasters.order(...)
```

Comment: I would do that but I have no way around it. I MUST override the sorting at a later time. I just need to solve the current issue but I do understand what you mean.

Comment: If your controller is that complex you could consider refactoring...
On possible workaround is to gather the ids on a separate query and then do an additional query to fetch the docs again, in the correct order. Or sort them in ruby space (if they are not too many).

Comment: I ended up moving the ordering to the end of the action so I don't need to overwrite it any longer. Thanks!